# "java org.w3c.dom.domexception invalid_character_err an invalid or illegal xml character is specified"

Tags: java, xml

While I run the below code exception is occurs "`java org.w3c.dom.domexception` invalid_character_err an invalid or illegal `xml` character is specified".

Please help me

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder builder=factory.newDocumentBuilder();
                org.w3c.dom.Document document = builder.parse("F:/shared/Manideep messg.xml");
                ((org.w3c.dom.Document) document).getDocumentElement().normalize();
                Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
                 Collection<Chat> ch = new ArrayList<Chat>();
                 ch.add(new Chat());

                 System.out.println(document.getElementsByTagName("chat"));

//creating user message tag
                 String conct = fromUser+"-"+toUser;
                 String[] split = conct.split(" ");

                 for (int i = split.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
                 {
                 usersTag += (split[i] + " ");
                 }

                msgTag=usersTag.trim();


                  org.w3c.dom.Element name=null;
                 if(document.getElementsByTagName(msgTag).getLength()==0)
                 {
                     System.out.println("in if condiotion");
                      name = (org.w3c.dom.Element) ((org.w3c.dom.Document) document).createElement(msgTag);
                        // ((Node) name).appendChild(((org.w3c.dom.Document) document).createTextNode(i.getMessage()));


     ((Node) root).appendChild((Node) name);
                         System.out.println("--------end of if");
                 }
                 NodeList list = document.getElementsByTagName(msgTag);
                 name= (Element) list.item(0);
                 System.out.println("Taag : "+name);
```

Comment: The error's quite clear: The XML document you're opening is malformed.

Comment: Thanks Chrylis. here my xml file.  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<chat>
<raju-mani><raju>hi</raju><mani>Hi</mani>
<raju>whr r u?</raju><mani>in U.S.</mani></raju-mani>
<deva-mani><deva>hw r u?</deva><mani>fine..</mani>
</deva-mani></chat>

Comment: That looks ok to me. Where is your code failing?, is it at the point of parsing your document, or later when building new nodes? Can you post stack trace and info on line numbers to match up in the code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error when executing code that was compiled with Java 7 under a Java 8 runtime. Either executing the older binary with Java 7 or rebuilding and then executing with Java 8 avoided the error.